# How to bind set of datatables to an HTML dynamic table with textboxes?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, html-table

How to bind set of datatables to an HTML dynamic table With textboxes?
I don't want use grid view because it's not customizable to my case. I want to customize an html table with textboxes.

If I have three datatable with the following structure:

```
1-Questions_dt(que_id,que_name)

1   Q1
2   Q2
3   Q3
```

---

```
2-Grades_dt(grade_id,grade_name,grade_weight)

    1  A  4
    2  B  3
    3  C  2
    4  D  1
    5  E  0
```

---

```
3-eval_dt(prog_ser,que_id,grade_id,lecturer_num)

1  1  1  15
1  1  2  6
1  1  3  33
1  1  4  2
1  1  5  2
```

Now I want to get some thing like that:

```
Questions                                Eval
              A             B              C           D          E
              4             3              2           1          0

   Q1         15(txtbox)    6(txtbox)      33(txtbox)  2(txtbox)  2(txtbox)
   Q2         (txtbox)      (txtbox)       (txtbox)    (txtbox)    (txtbox)
   Q3         (txtbox)      (txtbox)       (txtbox)    (txtbox)    (txtbox)

   Total      (Label)       (Label)        (Label)     (Label)     (Label)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net **repeater** and put anyone item to loop:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

```
   <form runat="server">
<asp:Repeater id="cdcatalog" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Artist</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Year</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("title")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("artist")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("country")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("company")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("price")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("year")%></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

Or you can use code direct in your view

```
<table> 
<tr> <td>TextBoxes</td> </tr> 
 <% foreach (DataRow dr in YourDataTable.Rows){ %>

<tr> <td> <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td> </tr>

<%}%>

</table>
```